# how to show entry from table if a variable is not present in my joined table?

Tags: sql, join

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions q JOIN answered a ON a.ans_qsId = q.qs_id WHERE a.ans_myId != '$id' ORDER BY q.qs_date ASC LIMIT 1;";
```

I have 1 table for questions and another table for who has answered which question.
I want a question to be loaded onto the page if the user's id is not present in the answered table (so they dont answer the same question again).

I'm not sure why my sql code is not working, I have tried many variations (also with LEFT), not managed to find an answer googling for an hour.

My answered table is empty at the moment, do I need something to say "if empty do this" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you a list of questions that are not listed in the answered table for a specific id.

```
SELECT * FROM questions q 
WHERE q.qs_id not in (select a.ans_qsId from answered a where a.ans_myId == '$id')
ORDER BY q.qs_date
```

Comment: sorry i just added an answered entry and it still shows the question

Comment: i removed the "!" from id lol, it appears you edited yours too.
Thank you for your answer :D